# libgstreamer-1.0-0.dll not found Gstreamer

Tags: windows-7, gstreamer, development-environment

I downloaded gstreamer devel 1.4.5 x86 and tried to compile basic tutorial 1 after addind property sheets, compilation went fine, but when I tried to run app, there was an error libgstreamer-1.0-0.dll not found. I tried to search web for solution but had no luck so far.
Any ideas?
Best regards

Answer (score 4):

You must download and install `Runtime msi` too. Runtime contain `Dlls`, Developer contain l`ib, headers and config`.

Comment: I only found E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\libgstreamer-1.0.dll.a. When I try to copy this file into E:\learn\gst-docs\examples\tutorials\vs2010\x64\Release, it gives error: E:\learn\gst-docs\examples\tutorials\vs2010\x64\Release\libgstsreamer-1.0-0.dll is either not designed to run on windows or it contains an error. Please help.

Comment: I download libgstreamer-1.0-0.dll 64 bit from https://www.pconlife.com/viewfileinfo/libgstreamer-1-0-0-dll/ But still no luck. It gives error:The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). click Ok to close the application.